# GNU guile: function registered with scm_c_define_gsubr: how can i handle an optional parameter?

Tags: c, optional-parameters, guile

I've defined a guile  C function:

```
static SCM myfun(SCM arg1,SCM opt_arg2)
  {
  return SCM_BOOL_T;
  }
```

registered with

```
scm_c_define_gsubr ("myfun", 1, 1, 0, myfun);
```

there is one **optional** argument. How can I detect if `opt_arg2` has been used ?

in

```
(myfun 1)
```

or

```
(myfun 1 2)
```

Comment: UPDATE: cross-posted on  https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/guile-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered on the guile-user mailing list: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/guile-user/2017-12/msg00045.html

citing: Alex Vong

From the Guile manual ``6.1 Overview of the Guile API'',

> For some Scheme functions, some last arguments are optional; the
>   corresponding C function must always be invoked with all optional
>   arguments specified.  To get the effect as if an argument has not been
>   specified, pass ‘SCM_UNDEFINED’ as its value.  You can not do this for
>   an argument in the middle; when one argument is ‘SCM_UNDEFINED’ all the
>   ones following it must be ‘SCM_UNDEFINED’ as well.

Therefore, we can check if opt_arg2 has the value SCM_UNDEFINED, to
decide if we have received an optional argument. The code is in the
attachment:

```
#include <libguile.h>

static SCM myfun(SCM arg1,SCM opt_arg2)
{
  if (scm_is_eq (opt_arg2, SCM_UNDEFINED))
    scm_display(scm_from_utf8_string("Optional argument NOT received!\n"),
                scm_current_output_port());
  else
    scm_display(scm_from_utf8_string("Optional argument received!\n"),
                scm_current_output_port());
  return SCM_BOOL_T;
}

void
init_myfun(void)
{
  scm_c_define_gsubr("myfun", 1, 1, 0, myfun);
}
```